# Search for multiple strings, print different values if present

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, data-cleaning, recode

I'd like to be able to search a column (say A) cell-by-cell and, if the cell contains certain strings (say "apple" or "pear"), print a certain value (say "A" or "P") in the corresponding cell of another column (say B).

So, if A1 has "pear", then B1 will say "P". If A1 has "apple", B1 will say "A".

What formula can I use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You need a lookup table in order to do the transformation. Put in cell `E2` the following formula:

```
=XLOOKUP(A2:A5,C2:C3,D2:D3,"")
```

and here is the output:

[image: sample excel file]

In case the fruit was not mapped, then it returns an empty string.

If you don't have in your excel version `XLOOKUP`, then you can use instead:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A5,C2:D3,2,0),"")
```

Comment: Great, thank you! Is there a way to have it do the same thing if the text isn't exactly the same as the search term but has that term embedded in a longer string? So, say the string could be "Apple", "xxxApple", "xAppleX", etc.